# How to replace the na with nothing in ggplot2 but not the other significance level?

Tags: ggplot2

I just want to have star(s) in my plot and not the na. How to replace the **na** with nothing in ggplot2 but not the other significance level?

Here is the script:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Gene, y=Count, fill=Stage))+
  geom_boxplot()+theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = 'black'))+
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 15.5,label = "p.signif")
```

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but here is one potential solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# use an example dataset
df <- ToothGrowth

# Default settings (has "ns")
ggplot(df, aes(x=supp, y=len, fill=dose))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = 'black'))+
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif")
```

[image]

```r
# Only plot the p.signif if it's <0.05
ggplot(df, aes(x=supp, y=len, fill=dose))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = 'black'))+
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = ifelse(..p.signif.. <= 0.05, ..p.signif.., "")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>